# Asset not found, but pubspec is correct and file exists

Tags: flutter

I have a problem, in `pubspec.yaml` I added new images through `- assets/images/google.png`, and also `- assets/images/notifications.png`, for some reason, I can use google.png image, but all the others - there is an error Asset not found, it's very strange, Flutter SDK is the latest version.

Don't say: "Check the syntax and the number of indents in this file", I checked, there are no errors anywhere, I did everything exactly the same as in the google.png example, it works."

In the screenshot you can see, the pubspec.yaml file, my code where I want to insert the image, and also on the left, the files, and above you can see that the files exist

```
════════ Exception caught by image resource service ════════════════════════════
The following assertion was thrown resolving an image codec:
Unable to load asset: "assets/images/test.png".
Exception: Asset not found
```

[image]

Comment: did you try to run `flutter pub get` and close your app and debug it again ?

Comment: try `flutter clean` and `flutter pub get` , then run again your . if still error, try to restrat your VScode

Comment: Yes, that's right, I disconnected the device, this was observed in the old version of Flutter as well, I really have no clue why this might be the case

Comment: Please add at least executable code to your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem myself:
If you use USB debugging and a smartphone, it helped me to export the app to an .apk with the --debug option

```
flutter build apk --debug
```

Also add the files to assets

Answer (score 2):

change this code

```
//- assets/images/test.png
- assets/images/
```

By specifying the directory path, you can access the files inside the directory.

finally

```
flutter clean
flutter pub get
```

Comment: Alas, the error remains

Comment: Does `pub get` of the `pubspec.yaml` file work normally?

Comment: Yeah, pubspec work normal

Answer (score 0):

Look at the below screenshot and compare the indentation (spacing). If you think everything is identical, you're good to go & if not? Then, make it.

Now, stop the current program and execute the below-mentioned commands in the project terminal one by one:

```
flutter clean
flutter pub get
flutter run
```

[image: View]

Comment: It didn't work, I did what you said

Comment: Could it be that it's because I have the app open on a physical Android rather than a PC?

Comment: Close everything, including the VSCode & then try to rebuild it.

Comment: The device doesn't matter, whether it is a physical or an emulator/simulator.

Answer (score -1):

Run
flutter clean
flutter pub get
Restart your App or Restart your VS Code.